# Domain redirection with folder separation. htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

After redirecting my client domain to my server i created rewrite rule in root folder .htaccess file to point domain to a subfolder1 (joomla website):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myclientdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/subfolder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder1/$1 [L]
```

Everything worked fine but today i found out that i can access any other subfolder in my server by entering for example: myclientdomain.com/subfolder2 and what's worse google can index that and show it in search results.

If there is any way to redirect a domain in a way that I won't be able to access any other folder on my server?

I would really appreciate help as I searched throughout google for answer, my server tech support said that they don't really support these kind of problems (they only gave me a piece of code from above) and I don't really know anything about .htaccess rules and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myclientdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder\/?(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder1/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change above rule to:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myclientdomain\.com$ [NC]
# if current URI is not starting with /subfolder/ then route to /subfolder/
RewriteRule ^((?!subfolder1/).*)$ subfolder1/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for response, I've tried your solution but I was still able to reach other subfolders in root folder of my server simply by putting myclientdomain.com/subfolder

Comment: There was a typo in my answer, it is fixed now. Make sure this is very first rule in your root .htaccess

Comment: Tried it, same problem. This is the first and in fact the only rule I have in .htaccess.

Comment: What URL are you using to test this rule and where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: OK, here's exactly what I have in my server rootfolder/.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?certyfikatpolski\.pl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!certj3/).*)$ certj3/$1 [L,NC]

my domain is certyfikatpolski.pl which points to rootfolder/certj3 but if you type in address bar certyfikatpolski.pl/ielement you will have access to my rootfolder/ielement which is completely different site

Comment: When I entered `http://www.certyfikatpolski.pl/` in browser it got redirected using `303` code to `http://www.certyfikatpolski.pl/pl/`. I don't see that is happening with the rule you've shown. Do you have more than one .htaccess?

Comment: In root folder I don't. In rootfolder/certj3 there is a Joomla! installation with it's own .htaccess. Joomla has multilanguage component which makes this redirection happen.

Comment: There is something seriously wrong with your config/setup. Even `http://www.certyfikatpolski.pl/certj3` get wrongly redirected to `http://www.certyfikatpolski.pl/pl/certj3`.  Which is not in any of the rules I provided above. You will need to fix Joomla installation.